# How to pass state parameters using epicurl libraries for Twitter oAuth signon

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have thus far been able to transmit a state in Google+ oAuth2, and Yahoo oAuth2, and even myopenid. Now I am at the Twitter stage of my provider login project.

I am using the three classes developed by @jmathai (tutorial [here](http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/09/23/sign-in-with-twitter-example/)).

My signin code looks very similar to this:

```
include 'EpiCurl.php';
include 'EpiOAuth.php';
include 'EpiTwitter.php';
$consumer_key = 'R4**Fw';
$consumer_secret = 'blp**Z8SA';

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

echo '<a href="' . $Twitter->getAuthorizeUrl() . '">
<img src="twitterButton.png" alt="sign in with twitter" />
</a>';
```

It works pretty well. But I need to pass some state parameters, like a client id, an origin page url, and some other junk.

I don't see how this is done with the epicurl libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. You can pass an entire query string, along with the url (although the page script should be the same as the callback page you specified in your Twitter app setup...I think).

```
include 'twitter-async-master/EpiCurl.php';
include 'twitter-async-master/EpiOAuth.php';
include 'twitter-async-master/EpiTwitter.php';

$consumer_key = 'R4kZPH********ZCtFw';
$consumer_secret = 'blp***********************klFcZ8SA';

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

$callback = "http://www.talqo.com/twittercallback.php?callback=".urlencode($_GET['callback'])."&domain=".urlencode($_GET['domain'])."&page=".urlencode($_GET['page'])."&tid=".urlencode($_GET['tid'])."&height=".urlencode($_GET['height'])."&width=".urlencode($_GET['height']);

$Twitter->setCallback($callback);
```

...and that's how it's done.